# How do I use ng-repeat with just one textarea?

Tags: angularjs

I want to place some text from an array in a textarea which users can copy and paste.
I have tried using ng-repeat but that creates a separate textarea for each item in the array. I realise I could use ng-model to populate the textarea but if I want to use ng-clip I would have to apply another ng-model to the textarea and I can't do that without an error.
Please see this plunker which shows the problem.
http://plnkr.co/edit/mDIP67sPx8A2xv6VNZxW?p=preview

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <textarea ng-repeat="person in persons">
      {{person}}!
    </textarea>
    <!--How do I use ng-repeat with just one textarea? -->
    <hr>
    <textarea ng-model="dogs">
    </textarea>
  <!-- I can get text from an array into a textarea with ng-model
  but I want to use ng-clip which requires ng-model also, and I can't have two
  models on the same element.-->
  </body>
```

Comment: What about creating an list inside the textarea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this perhaps?

```
<textarea>
  {{persons.join('!')}}
</textarea>
```

<s>http://plnkr.co/edit/vdQO6xEcyuwt4bfhudQB?p=preview</s>

Comment: Thanks this code does the job. (Your plunker has been altered from your code.)